onTap: como puedo ubicar esta función sin que de error
Estoy intentando colocar onTap en un Card, el cual tiene un Colum con los widgets Icon y Center, lo que forma el diseño de una tarjeta con un color de fondo, icono y Nombre al momento de colocarle el efecto de boton con la función onTap, genera un error, esto para poder accionar el onTap hacia una clase el cual viene siendo otra página para mostrar. A continuación coloco el código en dart y una imagen para que tengan idea de lo que se quiere hacer. En cualquiera de las linea que me he ubicado para colocar el onTap me genera error, es decir no se puede colocar esta función.

//import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:menulistview/listaBotones.dart';
//import 'package:menulistview/paginas/nuevaFactura.dart';

class pag_principal extends StatefulWidget {
  const pag_principal({super.key});

  @override
  State<pag_principal> createState() => _pag_principalState();
}

class _pag_principalState extends State<pag_principal> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
        ),
        itemCount: botones.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
              //elevation: 10,

              color: botones[index]["color"],
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    botones[index]["icono"],
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  Text(
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11, color: Colors.white),
                      botones[index]["nombre"]),
                ],
              ));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}[![En la imagen se muestra cada card con su icono y su Nombre, lo que quiero conseguir es que cada card funcione como botón y abra una nueva pagina ][1]][1]


Recuerda añadir siempre el error. ¿Dónde dices que has añadido el onTap? No lo veo en el código.

El error esta en cualquier línea que coloque el onTap, ejemplo si lo escribo dentro de los corchetes, juste debajo del widget Text, genera error, este es el error "Undefined name 'onTap'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name."

No puedes colocar el onTap donde te dé la gana. Para añadir un onTap, tienes que envolver el widget que quieras sea pursable con un GestureDetector o InkWell
